# Mid-90s sci-fi book about a boy who somehow gets transported to another world

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, young-adult, teleportation

It's about a boy who somehow gets transported to another world by a beam out of the sky. There were multiple beams, if I recall correctly.

I think I remember the beams being a timed occurrence, like every 7 or 10 years. And I think the book cover had a red background (like if it was dusk) and it showed multiple scattered blue beams coming out the sky.

He ends up living among a tribe; Native American or something along those lines. Marries a girl too. At the end someone in the tribe tells him of a way back to his home. I think they had found the same beams around the village.

That's as far as I can remember. I read it sometime in the 90's. I'm pretty sure it was young adult.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Young adult book about a boy(?) who gets sent through a portal to another world which is really the distant future](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/156631/young-adult-book-about-a-boy-who-gets-sent-through-a-portal-to-another-world)

Comment: @Shawn - our [current policy](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7065) for closing story-id questions as duplicates requires both questions to have the same accepted answer

Answer (score 4):

*The Transall Saga* by Gary Paulsen. The world he is transported to turns out to be a future Earth, decimated in the past by Ebola. [This](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwi2xb7JnJL9AhWLTUEAHZVBDPMQFnoECDUQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.goodreads.com%2Fen%2Fbook%2Fshow%2F121807&usg=AOvVaw3GB_7If5hG6IYcMFsbmSvz) looks like the cover you mention.

He doesn't get told about the beam that returns him, it's a bolt of lightning.