Looking for a book where a boy is transported to another world by a beam of light
I read this book around seven years ago. I don't remember much about the title, cover, or the author.

The main character is a boy he gets hit by a beam of light (definitely not lightning, per the answer from the other question similar to this one) and is transported into another world
He usually spends time alone and notices that there are weird animals (I forgot if they were sort of like the animals on Earth or not)
Eventually, he meets a group of people who are shorter than him by a lot and they ride on some sort of animal (maybe bison?)
He either falls in love or marries someone from the village
It turns out that there is a ruler that is also as tall as him, maybe from Earth too
He kills the ruler (I recall there being references to pits or something to kill the animals they were riding on)
He is hit by a beam of light

I don't know if the story ended there or not, but that's as far as my memory goes for the book.

Decent chance you may be talking about Gary Paulsen's The Transall Saga


While hiking through the mountains, thirteen-year old Mark Harrison is brought to an alien world where he must survive the new terrain and conflict with the planet's indigenous people. Mark is faced with the challenge of his life.

From the book:

He tried to remember. The light. There was the tube of blue light and then . . . the snake. He glanced at his hand, which was resting comfortably on his chest. It wasn't swollen at all. Even more curious, it didn't hurt.

....

He shrugged it off and continued to reason with himself. Okay, I'm in another world, possibly on another planet. One with red rubbery leaves and weird-looking animals. But I'm still me. My clothes are the same. I still get hungry. So what do I do now?

And from Super Summary:

Thinking he might be experiencing hallucinations, Mark stands up and looks around. Out of nowhere, a buffalo-like creature charges him, catching him off guard. He climbs into a tree to avoid it, managing to escape. Mark decides to navigate the thick brush of the jungle, and it starts to rain. He notices the rain tastes unusual. Searching for better-tasting water, he is attacked and bitten by insects. Panicking, Mark takes off his clothes to get the insects off. Just when he thinks the attack is over, he sees the buffalo creature again. He shimmies into a tree to avoid it. From the tree, he observes the creature eating his clothes. Realizing it doesn’t have good vision, he manages to steal some of his clothes back.

....

As Mark searches, he thinks of pizza and his parents. He uses his survival skills to forage food and create a temporary home. He wanders through the jungle until he finds an arrow in a tree. Anxious, Mark realizes this must mean there are other humans in the jungle with him. He discovers one such human in Leeta, a girl he saves from a terrifying creature known as the Howling Thing.

....

Despite the danger, Mark travels to see the Merkon; he wants answers about the nature of Transall. The Merkon explains that Transall is actually a future Earth, and that he was also transported to Transall by the beam of light in the 1980s. In this reality, an Ebola virus wiped out most humans years ago. The Merkon feels threatened by Mark and tries to kill him. Mark produces his own sword and brutally wounds the Merkon in a tense battle.

....

After leading the soldiers to the jungle he was first transported to, Mark hides behind a boulder. A violent storm strikes the boulder. The blue light reappears, and Mark is transported back to his own time. In the Epilogue, Mark is 20 years older. He is a scientist obsessed with curing Ebola, as he wants to save the world from Transall’s fate.

I've never actually read the book, but it was big when I was in school, so I remembered him being transported by blue light. The other plot point that most people remember is him realizing that he's the distant future when he finds an ancient artifact that is a glass coke bottle.

If so, it will be a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/156631/young-adult-book-about-a-boy-who-gets-sent-through-a-portal-to-another-world

Ah, it is a dupe.
